# Problem with Jquery AJAX and more than 2 variables

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to add a tell a friend section to a website I am making but I am having difficulty trying to send more than 2 variables through a URL with AJAX. This is the code I have at the moment:

```
    jQuery("#tellafriendsubmit").click(function() {

        var email = jQuery('#tellafriendemail').val();
        var name = jQuery('#tellafriendname').val();

            jQuery.ajax({
          type: "POST",
      url: "http://www.example.co.uk/tell-a-friend-processor-page/?postname=<?php echo $post_name; ?>&name=name&email="+email,

      success: function(msg){ 
            alert('Your tell a friend recommendation has been sent. Thank you for recommending us.');

      }
    });

});
```

If I remove the '&name=name' part so that I'm only sending the postname and email address, it works fine but I need to send the name as well so I can write 'Dear $name....'

How can I send the extra 3rd variable? Thanks for any help

Edit:

The part I'm using in the tellafriendprocessor page looks like this:

$email = $_POST['email'];
$post_name = $_GET['postname'];
$name = $_POST['name'];

```
             $to = $email;
             $subject = "Example - Tell a friend";
             $body = "Dear $name http://www.example.co.uk/ads/$post_name";

             if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {

              } else {

              }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try sending them as part of the POST request body (using the `data` property) which will ensure that those values are properly encoded:

```
var email = jQuery('#tellafriendemail').val();
var name = jQuery('#tellafriendname').val();
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://www.example.co.uk/tell-a-friend-processor-page/?postname=<?php echo $post_name; ?>',
    data: { name: name, email: email },
    success: function(msg) { 
        alert('Your tell a friend recommendation has been sent. Thank you for recommending us.');
    }
});
```

On the server side make sure you are reading them from the `$_POST` hash (`$_POST["name"]` and `$_POST["email"]`).

Comment: Hi Darin thanks for your answer, I've tried this but I still can't get it working (the alert function isn't displayed so it must be breaking before then). I've edited my question with what I have in the other file as well, could you see if I'm doing something wrong please?

Comment: @Daniel H, try analyzing with FireBug what AJAX request is sent to the server and the returned response. Also make sure there are no javascript errors. From what I can see you are subscribing to the click event of some button but you are not returning false from the .click callback at the end meaning that if `#tellafriendsubmit` is an anchor or a form submit button your AJAX will never have time to execute as the page will redirect. Also if the `$post_name` PHP variable contains some characters such as `'` they might break your javascript.

Comment: Hi Darin, I use firebug to look at HTML/CSS but I don't know how to see AJAX calls using it. Where abouts do I look? Thanks

Comment: @Daniel H, it's the `Console` tab. It is also where your javascript errors will be shown.

Comment: Thanks Darin, I'll use this alot from now on! :)

Comment: @Daniel H, so what was the problem? And, yes, FireBug is a *must have* for every web developer.

Answer (score 1):

you can send your parameters to a page with AJAX by GET and POST method with this piece of code

data: { id : 'id', name : 'name' },    // multiple data sent using ajax

Here is an example

$.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        cache:false,
        url:"welcome.php",
        data: { id : 'id', name : 'name' },    // multiple data sent using ajax
        success: function (html) {
          $('#add').val('data sent sent');
          $('#msg').html(html);
        }
      });

Answer (score 0):

You will need to move `name` outside the string. And to add more key-value-pairs you just append them to the query string: &key=value

```
url: "http://www.example.co.uk/tell-a-friend-processor-page/?postname=<?php echo $post_name; ?>&name="+name+"&email="+email
```

Comment: Hi Zanathel, sorry I should have mentioned in my question I've just put the value name in there to test it before I add in the javascript variable name, I've tried that too and it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try to use object of params like this:

```
$.post("/tell-a-friend-processor-page/", { name: "John", email: "<?php echo $post_email; ?>", post_name: "<?php echo $post_name; ?>" },
function(data) {
     alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
});
```